# Parallel installation of tankless electric hot water equipment with a boiler

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, hot-water

I have a normal, hot water system in my apartment with an electric boiler (40L). I would like to improve my hot water system and install a tankless instant electric hot water equipment, parallelly with the boiler.

This way:

```
                                tankless
                              instant heater
                              in  the shower
                                  |   |
          boiler tank, little     |   |
               bit far            X   X manual valves
                |  |              |   |  open/close
                X  X manual valves|   |
                |  |  open/close  |   |
                |  |              |   |
                |  |-> hot water -|---+-+
                |                 |     + -- mixing valve -- comfortable shower
--> cold water -+-----------------+-----+
```

My target is to save electrical consumption / have enough hot water when we have more guests in my apartment.

The outside temperature never goes below 15 degrees, the apartment is located on a sunny European island.

The `boiler` and the `instant heater` will be used exclusively which means that the two boiler valves will be closed manually when the instant heating equipment is used. Or if I use the boiler then I will close the valves of the `instant heater` and open the valves of the boiler.

If this new piping works properly then I am planning to use mainly the `instant heater` in the future.

Does this piping system work properly as I expect for a long time without any issues?

Comment: I am not loving the long "dead legs" in the pipe.  Put the cutout valves as close as possible to the ends of the pipe actually being cut out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine.  I would use ball valves because they are full flow when open and take only 1/4 turn to go from open to closed.  Presumably you will use appropriate materials and follow your local code.

Small sunny European island?  Maybe I should come take a look at your project...  ;)

Comment: Please come, I need craftsmen because the locals do not care too much about details. They do whatever they want despite I ask something different.

Comment: I don't know about that inspection trip, it gets as cold as 15 degrees.  You can get that in Chicago right now!  :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: @ Harper - Reinstate Monica - Point taken.  Actually, I was thinking more like June.  We'll be visiting friends in Ireland in late May, you see.